# How to parse from string to Int without .0 in Karate

Tags: string, parsing, integer, karate

I following the document of Karate Framework, to parse string to Int
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#floats-and-integers

- def foo = '10'
- string json = { bar: '#(1 * foo)' }
- match json == '{"bar":10.0}'
- string json = { bar: '#(parseInt(foo))' }
- match json == '{"bar":10.0}'

But in my case, I need to got a number without .0 such as '{"bar":10}' in above sample

Comment: I think this works fine in the latest version, but anyway - see linked answer